# MySQLi select instead of if

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

i got two tables

```
       Products
 ----------------------
 ProductId | ProdutName
     1     |    test
     2     |    test 2
```

and

```
                  SubProducts
 -----------------------------------------
 SubProductId | SubProductName | ProductId
      1       |    sub_test    |     1
      2       |    sub_test2   |     1
      3       |    sub_test3   |     1
      4       |    sub_test4   |     2
```

I want to get all rows from Product table and only the first row for every ProductId from SubProduct

As result i want this :

```
ProductId = 1
ProductName = test
SubProductId = 1
SubProductName = sub_test

ProductId = 2
ProductName = test2
SubProductId = 4
SubProductName = sub_test4
```

I did this with an if, but i know that this is wrong, so can it be done with one query?

I got this so far :

```
stmt = $connection->stmt_init();

if ($stmt->prepare("
  SELECT DISTINCT a.`ProductId`, a.`ProductName`, b.`SubProductId`, b.`SubProductName`
  FROM `Products` as a, `SubProducts` as b
  WHERE b.ProductId=a.ProductId
"))
{

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($product_id, $product_name, $sub_product_id, $sub_product_name);

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
      if ($current_id!=$product_id)
      {
        echo 'id = '.$product_id;
        echo 'thumb = '.$sub_product_name;

        $current_id = $product_id;
      }
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.`ProductId`, a.`ProductName`, b.`SubProductId`, b.`SubProductName`
FROM `Products` as a, `SubProducts` as b
WHERE 
b.`ProductId`=a.`ProductId`
group by  a.`ProductId`
```

Check the link in **SQL Fiddle** :  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71778f/1/0

Comment: @user2564276 check the SQL Fiddle link

Comment: i accept the answer but i cant upvote :/ low rep! can u also help me with another query? its the next after this one, so can i edit this question?